# Is it possible to combine spline IK for the body and regular IK for limbs?

Tags: armature, inverse-kinematics, splines

I've got a centipede model with an IK rig. [image: IK-rigged centipede model in a room with spline curve in background, moving along the walls.]
I would like the spine to move along the spline curve in the background, following its curvature, while still letting me pose the legs like normal to make it look like it's running along the wall. None my attempts have worked out - either the body won't stick to the curve properly or I'm unable to move the legs without them glitching out.

[Here's a link to an album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCvSd.jpg) where I list the methods I've tried so far, including gifs of what the model looks like trying to move along the curve.

Answer (score 0):

as far as your question goes it is possible, it has to be set-up correctly - Where is your 'Spline IK' ??

> I would like the spine to move along the spline curve in the
>   background, following its curvature

That would be a 'Path' and could be done several ways 'Clamp To' or 'Path' constraint. The set-up on the legs does not look good to me, your leg bones with the IK should be shifted forward to what is prob the current IK targets and a new or that large bone re=scaled to be the IK targets. That is why the legs are 'Glitching out' on you. I will try and mock up a file for you if you want.
DISCLAIMER: This file created in v2.76 - If using 2.7x it will open fine,, If using 2.8x 'APPEND' the objects from the 'Object' folder.

[image]

Comment: I'd love to see your mockup file, because I'm not exactly sure what I should be changing. https://easyupload.io/hgq3vo I've uploaded the file here, in case you want to take a look at it.

Comment: I had a look at your file - the mesh object would be better if you had 'Edge Loops' where the bones bend (deform) it. The armature its self is scaled and rotated, you should 'Apply' that before Parenting(Weighting) the mesh to it, although I did it without any bad effects - The rigging is not that optimal unfortunately, I'm posting the file in my original post so you can have a look, Thanx

Comment: Thanks for the file! I spent a little bit of time fiddling with it and it's a perfect solution to what I want to do, and the rig itself is very well-made too. Did you use a tool or plug-in to help you? The .blend file came with a macro that wanted to execute - didn't let it, but it works fine without.

Comment: Your Welcome,No plug-in, Thanks for the heads up on Macro - will look into that.